# Conditional inclusion of projects in Visual Studio solution files

Tags: c#, msbuild, solution, csproj

I am developing a set of interdependent libraries, and I would like to generate several versions of these libraries, targetted at different .NET framework versions. Sure enough, this is a common issue and there is plenty of documentation available on how to write `.csproj` files in such a way that either the (more frequently mentioned) `configuration` or the (IMHO much better suited) `platform` variable includes a choice for the target framework.

All of the libraries are in a common solution.

Now, some of the libraries have external dependencies that are only available on newer .NET framework versions. Hence, for the older versions, building the respective projects makes no sense.

**How can I exclude some of the projects based upon the selected `platform`?**

I imagine the answer to this problem must be one of these ways, but I could not find any concrete information on how to do this:

- Either, it must be a setting in the `.sln` file that allows me to conditionally exclude some of the projects from the solution. From the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951.aspx), it doesn't get clear to me whether any of the projects in the `.sln` file can be marked to be built only when a given set of settings is active.
- Or, it might be a setting in the `.csproj` file that allows me to conditionally disable compilation (not making compilation fail, rather indicating the project should not currently be built). My first guess was the [`OutputType` setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb629394.aspx), but it only allows `Library`, `Exe`, `Module`, and `Winexe`; there is no value such as `None`.

Of course, there is the workaround of creating a separate `.sln` file per .NET framework version, but this sounds cumbersome (and hence error-prone), given that any future additional library would have to be added to each of the `.sln` files, so there would be a lot of duplication of solution code and a lot of duplicate effort.

*I prefer learning how to do this in the source code of `.sln` and/or `.csproj` files.*

Comment: Either I don't understand your question, or else just open VS, right-click the solution, select `Configuration Manager...`, adjust `Build` checkbox to taste?

Comment: @stijn: I don't have VS (the allegedly free Community Edition keeps telling me *Your license has expired.*); I have always been using SharpDevelop for development, and its configuration manager looks just like VS's, except for lacking the *build* and *deploy* columns. Therefore, a description of what has to be changed in the `.sln` and/or `.csproj` source to achieve the behaviour controlled by that checkbox could be a valid answer to this question.

Comment: For VS it just comes down to deleting the corresponding `{Project GUID}.Configuration|Platform.Build.0` line, is that what you're after? Question is also whether SharpDevelop supports that. On a sidenote: the VS2015 community edition is running fine for our team.

Comment: Some teams use MSBuild project files for builds instead of Visual Studio solution files. MSBuild can consume a solution file but it does so by translating it to an MSBuild project. If you want to see it, `set msbuildemitsolution=1`. You could then make it your own and use it for your builds.